# Is it possible to build the same program twice in OpenCL with different preprocessor options.

Tags: opencl

Given the following code, wher P is a cl_program loaded with some source code.
What happens if i run

```
*err = clBuildProgram (p, 
                       1,
                       m_gpu_device_id,
                       str0,   // Compiler options, see the specifications for more details
                       0, 
                       0);

cl_kernel kernel0= clCreateKernel (p,   // The program where the kernel is
                        "nn_feedforward",   // The name of the kernel, i.e. the name of the kernel function as it's declared in the code
                        err);

*err = clBuildProgram (p,1,m_gpu_device_id, str1 ,0, 0);
cl_kernel kernel1 = clCreateKernel (p, "nn_feedforward", err);
```

Will the kernel1 work with the options of str1 in contrast to kernel0 with str0 options. or will the first kernel get written over in some way.

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: I was able to build it, but as i am still learning, i havent been able to test if it produced different kernels.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you shouldn't get two, different, valid kernels.

Comment: Seems that it is not building after all. The second build call gives an -59 error and specifikations tells that this error is for when the previous build call is not completed. But i have made sure and i know it is completet before it get to the second call.

Comment: Had to create two programs, meaning copying the source code twice. Seems abit supid.